# Normal of a coons patch at a given point

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d, surfaces

**Disclamer:** Rendering the Coons patch is part of 3D Graphics homework, but finding the normals at a given point isn't. Just curious.

Here's what I got so far:

[image]

It's a Coons patch defined by four Hermite curves. I render the Coons patch by making a mesh of triangles from points calculated on the Coons patch.

The surface could look much smoother than it actually is if I could figure out how to get the normal of the patch at any given point, instead of using the normals of the flat triangles.

Now I know that if I have two tangents of the surface at a given point, their cross product will give me what I look for. I also know that, for an Hermite curve in 2D space, finding the tangent means getting the derivative, which is easy if you see Hermite curve as a product of matrixes and the vector (1, t, t^2, t^3); just use this vector instead (0, 1, 2t 3t^2). The normal is just the perpendicular of the tangent then:

[image]

But how do I translate that knowledge into finding the two tangents necessary for finding the normal of the Coons patch at a given point? My shaky programmer maths fail me.

**EDIT: Here's how I build my Coons patch. Taken at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coons_patch#Bilinear_blending). The 4 curves are Hermites.**

Given four space curves c<sub>0</sub>(s), c<sub>1</sub>(s), d<sub>0</sub>(t), d<sub>1</sub>(t) which meet at four corners c<sub>0</sub>(0) = d<sub>0</sub>(0), c<sub>0</sub>(1) = d<sub>1</sub>(0), c<sub>1</sub>(0) = d<sub>0</sub>(1), c<sub>1</sub>(1) = d<sub>1</sub>(1); linear interpolation can be used to interpolate between c<sub>0</sub> and c<sub>1</sub>, that is

$L_c(s,t)=(1-t) c_0(s)+ t c_1(s) $

and between d<sub>0</sub>, d<sub>1</sub>

$L_d(s,t)=(1-s) d_0(t)+ s d_1(t) $

producing two ruled surfaces defined on the unit square.

The bilinear interpolation on the four corner points is another surface

$ B(s,t) = c_0(0) (1-s)(1-t) + c_0(1) s(1-t) +  c_1(0) (1-s)t + c_1(1) s t. $

A **bilinearly blended Coons patch** is the surface

$L_c(s,t)+L_d(s,t)-B(s,t). $

Comment: I assume you have 8 triangles that meet at each vertex of your mesh. You could use the average of the 8 normals of these triangles. That will give you nicer shading.

Comment: @bubba That's a good idea. Why make it if I can fake it? If it turns out to be too complicated to find tangents on a bilinearly blended Coons patch, I'm taking this approach.

Comment: Averaging normals gives [very smooth results](http://i.imgur.com/T1iOCkh.png). I've went for that… and I've added Mortenson to my reading todo list :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "Coons patch" is used to refer to several different surface types in CAGD, unfortunately. It sounds like you're talking about a standard tensor-product bicubic patch, which can be written in Hermite form:
$$
\mathbf{S}(u,v) = [1 \; u \; u^2 \; u^3] \cdot \mathbf{M} \cdot [1 \; v \; v^2 \; v^3]^T
$$
where $\mathbf{M}$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix containing corner points, derivative vectors, and "twist" vectors. There's a good description of these creatures in [this book by Mortenson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0831132981).

You can just differentiate the patch equation from above to get partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial u}(u,v) = 
[0 \; 1 \; 2u \; 3u^2] \cdot \mathbf{M} \cdot [1 \; v \; v^2 \; v^3]^T
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial v}(u,v) = 
[1 \; u \; u^2 \; u^3] \cdot \mathbf{M} \cdot [0 \; 1 \; 2v \; 3v^2]^T 
$$
Then, as you mentioned, the normal is just the cross product of the partial derivative vectors
$$
\mathbf{N}(u,v) = 
\frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial u} \times 
\frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial v}
$$
You should unitize this normal vector before using it in lighting calculations, of course.

**Edit:**
From the modified question, we now know that the Coons patch is actually a bilinearly blended "boolean sum" one:
$$
\mathbf{S}(u,v) = \mathbf{L}_c(u,v) + \mathbf{L}_d(u,v) - \mathbf{B}(u,v)
$$
The process described above will work on these kinds of patches, too (or on any parametric surface, actually). We just have to compute partial derivatives, again. These are straightforward:
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{L}_c}{\partial u} = (1-v)\mathbf{c}'_0(u) + v\mathbf{c}'_1(u)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{L}_d}{\partial u} = \mathbf{d}_1(v) - \mathbf{d}_0(v)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial u} = 
(1-v)\big[\mathbf{c}_0(1) - \mathbf{c}_0(0)\big] +
    v\big[\mathbf{c}_1(1) - \mathbf{c}_1(0)\big]
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{S}}{\partial u} = 
\frac{\partial\mathbf{L}_c}{\partial u} +
\frac{\partial\mathbf{L}_d}{\partial u} -
\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial u}
$$
And similarly for the partial derivatives with respect to $v$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't realize Coons patch refer to different surface types :( I've updated my question to detail how I define my surface. Could I still find normals using this method?